# Visual bug in the raytracer?

Tags: python, graphics, raytracing

[image: scene]

I do not know if this is a bug or normal behavior, but I am confused by an elongated object in the reflection of a red sphere, what is it?

My scene:

```py
s = Scene(
    [
        Light(
            type_=LightType.ambient, 
            intensity=vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
        ),
        Light(
            type_=LightType.point, 
            intensity=vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6), 
            position=vec3(2, 1, 0)
        ),
        Light(
            type_=LightType.directional,
            intensity=vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 
            direction=-vec3(1, 4, 4)
        ),
    ],
    [
        Triangle(vec3(-1.5, 0.5, 5.2), vec3(1.5, 0.5, 5.2), vec3(-1.5, 2, 4), vec3(0, 0, 0), 500, 1),
        Triangle(vec3(1.5, 0.5, 5.2), vec3(1.5, 2, 4), vec3(-1.5, 2, 4), vec3(0, 0, 0), 500, 1),
        Sphere(
            color=u8vec3(255, 0, 0), 
            radius=1, 
            center=vec3(0, -1, 3),
            specular=500,
            reflective = 0.2
        ),
        Sphere(
            color=u8vec3(0, 0, 255), 
            radius=1, 
            center=vec3(2, 0, 4),
            specular=500,
            reflective=0.3
        ),
        Sphere(
            color=u8vec3(0, 255, 0), 
            radius=1, 
            center=vec3(-2, 0, 4),
            specular=10,
            reflective=0.4 
        ),
        Sphere(
            color=u8vec3(255, 255, 0), 
            radius=5000, 
            center=vec3(0, -5001, 0),
            specular=1000,
            reflective=0.5
        )
    ]
)
```

full code is here: https://github.com/linux-admin0001/raytracer

Comment: [scene](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/73735838/214915833-47582b84-06bb-4a90-a05e-7bd3ac058e2e.png)

Comment: I marked it with a red marker

Comment: Now I see it you have it in reflections also on blue and maybe also on green ball but it look more like lighting bug then real object, can you increase/decrease max number of ray recursion to see if it changes? maybe its just that the artifact needs one more layer of recursion then neighboring pixels and its already cut of ...

Comment: I set the recursion depth to 50 (there were 4)

Comment: but the result remained the same

Comment: [what](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/73735838/215267104-8ae283d1-b3e2-4654-a4cb-82861880e8cf.png)

Comment: [image with marked visual bugs](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/73735838/215267247-6b44960b-425c-4504-ad6b-f7c4c0141b16.png)

Comment: Before that I thought there were shadows on the sides

Comment: here I changed the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Fixed version]

I'm fixed this bug.

My mistake was that the ray intersected with the object without taking into account the direction of the ray, let's say the ray was directed forward (0, 0, 1), but it also intersected the object that was behind, I corrected this for triangles, for spheres I did not observe this

```py
if dot(D-O, object_.normal) > 0: continue
```

As you can see, in the final image I got rid of many distortions that seemed to me to be serviceable